# How to refresh or reload a div's content using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is somehow. i normally use jquery's load to load content from page A into page B , so loading a div's content into itself in order to just refresh it doesn't make much sense. What's the solution for this?

```
$('#A').load('pageX.php #A');
```

Please note that both #As are on pageX making it the same #A

This somehow interferes with the JavaScript in a bad way after that "load" i don't know why.

So these is simply to refresh a div.

Comment: You can't have repeating ID's, fix that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `id` must to unique in html document otherwise you'll end up having expected results for JavaScript.

In your case you need to remove duplicate `id's`

Something like this

```
$('#A').load('pageX.php #B');
```

or this will work:

```
$('#B').load('pageX.php #A');
```

Comment: It's not duplicate, it's itself, please read the question again.

Comment: Can't understand what you are asking then. Can you paste HTML?

Comment: Ok I'll paste html. Question is. "How to refresh a div using jquery's ajax load

Comment: It'll be refreshed itself when new content comes in?

Comment: Wot that load a copy of #A inside #A? One needs to code it I'm such a way as to only load content not present in itself.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not following you. Please paste relevant HTML and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Because of people coming to this question, if I were to do this again now, I would do it like this.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="divToRefresh"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript(JQuery)**

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.refreshDiv = function(arg){
        var d = {someVariable_you_can_send:arg}
        $.ajax({
            url:'url_to_div_content',
            data:d,
            type:"POST"}).done(function(result){
                $('.divToRefresh').html(result);    
            });     
    };
    //////////call this for the first time//////////
    $.refreshDiv('some value');
    //////////////////////////// and then refresh it after a certain interval if you need to
    window.setInterval(function(){
        $.refreshDiv('some value');
    }, 1000*60*60*60);

});
</script>
```